# Google chrome search suggestions aren't functioning correctly while logged in

Tags: google-chrome

When typing in the Google Chrome search bar, a very limited selection of suggestions is given, with no suggestions given after the third word has been typed. This only occurs while I am logged in to my google account, and no issue is present when using incognito. The issue is present in both the address bar and the main google search.

This issue started a week ago, seemingly for no reason. I am not currently running any extensions for Google Chrome.

An example is shown below of the difference between my logged in google search suggestions and those i get in incognito mode.

[image: logged in image][image: incognito image]

The same issue occurs on my phone using the google chrome android app, but does not occur when using different accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved 10 days after emergence, but the solution was not clear. Shortly before it resolved, in my google account settings I disabled and reenabled private searches (https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en-GB), but this did not appear to immediately resolve the problem. It may have simply been a coincidence that the issue resolved shortly after this.